# cant use make to execute Makefile (to download the drivers from cd)

Tags: linux, kali-linux, drivers, make

i cant use make to execute the file .

I have a problem when installing the drivers from cd
i use Kali Linux

I tried to apt update and apt upgrade but nothing helped me.

This is the problem:

```
$ sudo make clean
[sudo] password for user: 
#make -C /lib/modules/5.7.0-2-amd64/build M=/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02 clean
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*/*.mod.c */*/*/*.mod */*/*/*.o */*/*/.*.cmd */*/*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
user@Dix:~/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02$ sudo make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.7.0-2-amd64/build M=/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c: In function ‘rtw_txpwr_init_regd’:
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:260:6: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  260 |   if (rfctl->regd_name)
      |      ^
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:262:2: note: here
  262 |  default:
      |  ^~~~~~~
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c: In function ‘mgt_dispatcher’:
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:1349:17: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
 1349 |    ptable->func = &OnAuthClient;
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:1351:2: note: here
 1351 |  case WIFI_ASSOCREQ:
      |  ^~~~
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_chplan.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/mesh/rtw_mesh.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_pathtbl.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_hwmp.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_rson.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_rm.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_rm_fsm.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/rtw_rm_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.o
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2224:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_da’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 2224 |   set_fs(get_ds());
      |          ^~~~~~
      |          get_da
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2224:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2224 |   set_fs(get_ds());
      |          ^~~~~~~~
      |          |
      |          int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/osdep_service.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2262:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2262 |    set_fs(get_ds());
      |           ^~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/osdep_service.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2297:11: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
 2297 |    set_fs(get_ds());
      |           ^~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           int
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/uaccess.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/task.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/include/linux/sched/signal.h:9,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/osdep_service.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.c:19:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:40: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘int’
   29 | static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:272: /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/Makefile:1745: /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:2327: modules] Error 2
user@Dix:~/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02$ make install
install -p -m 644 8192fu.ko  /lib/modules/5.7.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8192fu.ko': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:2333: install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your system is fully up-to-date, and then install your kernel headers to provide `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` which is the missing part causing the error:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Reboot, and check you’re running [5.7.6-1kali2](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux) (as of this writing), and then install the headers:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: done but there is next problem how i can text u because i cant comment it its too long

Comment: ------i make everything correct  but there is next problem how i can text u because i cant comment it its too long $ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.7.0-2-amd64/build M=/home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02/driver/rtl8192FU_rtl8725AU_WiFi_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0d02  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/RTL8192FU_RTL8725AU_linux_v5.8.6.2_35538.20191028_COEX20190910-0      ----there is more but maximum chars on comments

Comment: please add the whole log to your original post (click `edit` below the post and put it in, take care to format it as code, otherwise it will be hard to read)

Comment: Try this: First run `sudo make clean`, then run `sudo make` and if that **succeeds** run `make install`. If there are any errors, add them to your original post.

Comment: @toydarian that should be `make clean && make`, no need for `sudo` there. But it won’t work anyway, see [the follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604322/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt I thought that, if he built with `sudo`, `make clean` without `sudo`, might fail. You are right about the follow-up. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @toydarian true, so `sudo make clean`, but then `make` ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt i put the errors please check it

Comment: @toydarian check it pleases

Comment: @Dizaster199 you’ve been told what the problem is on your other question.

Comment: @StephenKitt what should i do please