# i want to let my kali linux recognize my wifi adapter

Tags: kali-linux, compiling, make

I am using Kali Linux. I tried

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I got this problem when I use `make` to execute Makefile

I am trying to install drivers for wifi adapter, chipset = rt3070 from cd its come with it.

```
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)



$ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:c4:99:26:4d:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12  bytes 556 (556.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 556 (556.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b333:8bf2:c17f:6ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                                                                              
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1152  bytes 464903 (454.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1260  bytes 216120 (211.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  I have edited your post for you, but for next time, please see [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts. Please also [edit] your post and give us some context. Tell us what operating system you are using (you tagged with Debian, but which one?), explain what you are trying to do and what is happening.

Comment: @terdon thank u so much i use kali linux

Comment: As I said, please ***edit*** your question and explain. Also, Kali is _not_ Debian. Kali is a tool for professional security experts. If you don't know how to solve this sort of thing, you probably shouldn't be using Kali. Anything you can do with Kali, you can do with any other Linux, so if you're just learning, start with another one and install Kali tools if you must. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360)

Comment: @terdon kali linux is based on debian . iam learing security . but iam new

Comment: Where did  you get the driver from?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it comes with the wifi adapter bt-n9100

Comment: @Dizaster199 "based on" only means that it inherits some (most) packages.  But it's maintained by a completely different group of people with a completely different release cycle.  It's reliability and ease of use are completely different.  Please understand that directing users to us Debian rather than Kali comes from a lot of experience helping people.  Kali is not a good learning environment - ever.

Comment: This error looks suspiciously like [a similar error for a different wifi driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/30).  They traced the problem back to a [linux kernel change](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/736706bee3298208343a76096370e4f6a5c55915) that.  In short the driver you have isn't compatible with newer kernels.  So you either need a newer driver or an older kernel.

Comment: You repeatedly use the word "this" to refer to an error. What is the error?

Comment: If you are new to Gnu/Linux, then don't use kali.

Comment: sorry i edit the title .@ctrl-alt-delor no iam not new but iam facing problems while installing driver

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving the following error because the actual module could not be compiled, therefore, when you run `sudo make install` 8192fu.ko can't be found and moved to the wireless modules directory.
`install: cannot stat '8192fu.ko': No such file or directory`

Check [this git repository](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) for newer drivers and an easier install.

Comment: i tried it and i got no errors but the wifi adapter still  not recognized @who8mypnuts

Comment: Two possibilities: using `lspci` or `lsusb` see if your device is recognized by the OS. If so, make sure using ifconfig to turn the wireless device on and get it up and running.  If not, [try this driver as an alternative](https://github.com/blackPantherOS/rtl8192fu)  If the `insmod` command works, then move it to the kernel/network/wireless folder as previously included and run `sudo depmod` which should make it permanent.

Comment: please check up i edit and paste the ifconfig and lspci <3

Comment: bro its the built in nic

Comment: Did you try compiling the alternative driver for your kernel and using `insmod`?

Comment: sudo insmod then what ?

Comment: i tried depmod but nothing happend

Comment: You'll need to compile the driver, and then `insmod drivername`  If this is successful, then you should see your wireless device working. That's when you would copy the driver over to the proper module location on the system. The information is included in the link above to the git page for the driver.

Comment: and how i can now the proper module location i make git clone https...   on /home/user

Comment: -----------ls
clean  core  dkms.conf  hal  ifcfg-wlan0  include  Kconfig  Makefile  os_dep  platform  README.md  runwpa  wlan0dhcp ------------
i typed make and then ls this i got what is drivername <3

Comment: please help its last step brother

Comment: The driver will be called `8192fu.ko`

Comment: If the `insmod 8192fu.ko` works, you'll need to copy this file via sudo to the kernel modules folder you tried originally, but had the failure because the module was missing.

Comment: i got ---$ insmod 8192fu.ko
bash: insmod: command not found

Comment: `sudo insmod 8192fu.ko` inside the directory where you compiled the driver, correct?

Comment: yes ofc in the directory

Comment: Did the wifi adapter work when you did insmod or you just got the command not found only?

Comment: no didn't work idk why

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm a bit at a loss at this point.